# If I extend a c# interface, can I eat a call?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface

In this question I mention Unity3D, but applies generally in c#.

Unity3D has an Interface that looks like this ..

```
public class SomeRobot:MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler
    {
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
        {
        Debug.Log("Gets called whenever someone touches the screen...");
        }
```

No problem so far.

I make my own interface..

```
public interface IFUHandler:IPointerDownHandler
    {
    void OnBlah (PointerEventData data);
    }
```

Assume I have a daemon or whatever that calls OnBlah for consumers of the interface.

```
public class SomeRobot:MonoBehaviour, IFUHandler
    {
    public void OnBlah(PointerEventData data)
        {
        Debug.Log("Gets called when blah happens...");
        }
```

No problem so far.  BUT

```
public class SomeRobot:MonoBehaviour, IFUHandler
    {
    public void OnBlah(PointerEventData data)
        {
        Debug.Log("Gets called when blah happens...");
        }
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
        {
        Debug.Log("this DOES still get called also...");
        }
```

In fact, `OnPointerDown` still gets called. Which makes sense.

BUT .... is there a way for my Interface **to eat the calls to OnPointerDown**?

So that a consumer subscribing to `IFUHandler` in fact **does NOT get** the calls to `OnPointerDown`?

(But of course gets my `OnBlah` calls.)

Or am I just suffering "TMIOOK" thinking?  (Tied Myself In OO Knots thinking  :) )

Comment: This is a very interesting question.  I will experiment to see if this is even possible.

Comment: [PointerEventData](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData.html) has a [used](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.AbstractEventData-used.html) member. Can you set that to `true` to stop anything else reacting to it?

Comment: Hi @ChrisF - well .. I mean, where?!  (Also, that - I guess - wouldn't really help in the "general c# question" situation....I think.)

Comment: @JoeBlow - True. Though in the general case a lot of events do have a "Handled" property.

Comment: @JoeBlow what do you want to achieve?

Comment: hey @UmairM - as it says, in the example described  *"In fact, OnPointerDown still gets called"*

Comment: Yah I read that. I mean what do you want to achieve by eating up `OnPointerDown` call? What's the reason  behind all this custom interface setup?

Comment: Umair, I think it's obvious you may want something "like" IPointerDownHandler (for example) but get rid of some calls and add new ones. IN any event: Illedan (& Everts comment) has largely answered the question!  Good one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

Possible solutions:

1. Don't inherit `IPointerDownHandler` when you don't need it. Why do you need this interface if you aren't going to use it?
2. Create a Sealed Abstract class with a non-virtual method

   ```
   public class BaseFUHandler : MonoBehaviour, IFUHandler
   {

   public abstract void OnBlah(PointerEventData data);

   public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
   {
       //Gets called, but nothing hapends.
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for that - indeed often a clear "No" is the most useful answer.

Comment: Anyone reading this may enjoy my somewhat related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576493 (which, however, is relevant only to Unity, not c# generally).

Comment: I also vote for no. If that interface is declared, it should mean that the interface is meaningful for that object to work out properly. If there should be a ghost method, then something is wrong.